# Why is the config server string order sensitive when launching mongos?

Tags: mongodb

and thanks in advance for your time.

For a given sharded setup, mongos is launched while specifying the config server(s) to talk to. Say we start with the following mongos option:

```
--configdb=cf1,cf2,cf3
```

Everything is all fine and dandy. If you were to relaunch mongos (or launch a different mongos) with:

```
-- configdb=cf3,cf2,cf1
```

It results in the following error:

```
Tue Jul  9 23:32:41 uncaught exception: error: { "$err" : "could not initialize sharding on connection rs1/db1.me.net:27017,db2.me.net:27017,db3.me.net:27017, :: caused by :: mongos specified a different config database string : stored :cfg1:27017,cfg2:27017,cfg3:27017 vs given :cfg3:27017,cfg2:27017,cfg1:27017","code" : 15907}
```

My question is, what is the reasoning mongo sensitive to the order of the config server string? I would imagine at some point it parses the different servers hostnames/port, so why not just compare the set? I know you can see from the [source code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/s/d_state.cpp) that its just a string comparison, but my question is the underlying reason for this.

Some context to this problem: I am using chef for my mongo deployments. We recently went through the exercise of [migrating the config server with the same hostname](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/migrate-config-servers-with-same-hostname/). However, this still ended up being a disruptive process because the order the chef picked up the config servers had changed, thus changing order mongos starts its process with. I understand that this issue is directly because of chefs functionality, but I am curious as to why Mongo is not this flexible.

Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `mongos` process changes metadata for sharded cluster, it has to change it in all three config servers "simultaneously" (i.e. all three must agree in order to have a valid metadata change).

If the system were to go down in the middle of such a metadata change, if the config database order was not fixed, there would be a lot more possible permutations of incorrect states to unwind.  Requiring a fixed sequence of config dbs allows (a) simpler checking of whether all members of the cluster are viewing the same metadata (b) significant reduction of possible states when a system crashes or otherwise stops unexpectedly.

In addition it reduces chances for "race condition" sorts of bugs if different `mongos'` could initiate the same operations on different config servers.   Even as simple a change as `mongos` process taking a "virtual" distributed lock to see if a chance is necessary - how could you handle the case of different `mongos'` checking config servers in different order to check on (and take out) the lock?

As a summary, the three config servers are *not* a replica set, but one of them still has to be the one that always accepts the changes "first" - think of the order of configdbs to mongos as designation of such "first" status.